# WebSockets: Any working C# examples?

Tags: asp.net, html, websocket

I'm using Chrome 5.0.375.86. Can anyone point me to a working example of an HTML page communicating (or at least establishing a handshake) in Chrome with a C# (faux) web server?

The current version of WebSockets in hixons-76 (or whatever) and not -75. What does production Chrome currently support? I think it's -75. Do I need the nightly build for -76?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# web socket server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-web-socket-server)

Comment: The above http://nugget.codeplex.com/ not able to run. Is it because of different version of Chrome browser ?

Answer (score 1):

This is also a nice example (The author says it should work with -76)

http://nugget.codeplex.com/

[Heres a Related Question on SO, Should help you to get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-web-socket-server)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find useful my demo http://programistka.com/en/websockets-c/ which uses two open source libraries - one for server and one for client. In my opinion it is really worth to check them.