# Using socket.io standalone without node.js

Tags: javascript, windows, websocket

(JavaScript newbie)

I am trying to build a JavaScript based client app that communicates with a server app over socket. I came across [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Is it possible to use socket.io without any node.js dependencies?

I have cloned socket.io github and wrote a simple client html to connect to the server (Can post the code if required). But it does not connect to the server.

(Background info: We need a simple config client utility that runs on Win32 that communicates with a custom server that supports socket communication with a custom packet-format protocol. Instead of going through the usual MFC/.NET, we think HTML/JS/CSS makes a better solution. For this purpose, I have considered the following options:

1. Titanium: Works, but requires runtime to be installed
2. HTML5 WebSocket: Not widely supported - works on Chrome but requires IE10
3. socket.io: Trying to get it to work
4. Any other?
   (Can post this question as separate thread, if necessary)
   )

Comment: Just use node-iis and socket.io together

Comment: What language do you write the server in?

Comment: There's a project put together by Guillermo Rauch, entitled "Socket.io, Sockets for the rest of us" It does just what you're looking for, socket.io functionality without the added complexity of node.js https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

Answer (score 6):

Establish a successful Socket.IO, your custom server must follow [the spec](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io-spec), or use other server implementation of socket.io
https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki the **In other languages** part include some servers implementation of socket.io

Comment: Thank you very much. I would love to try it out and accept the answer if it works. But I have moved on to a few other things (oh, the travails of the dictated corporate world!). I will get to this as soon as I can. And thanks much for your time time and effort again.

Comment: Thumbs up for the spec, but the wiki is no longer available, it seems socket.io is now maintained by Automattic. I couldn't find an equivalent page that listed __other languages__ implementations.

Comment: Broken link. It redirects to: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io which has no wiki. Try: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/wiki and you get redirected back to the repo (first link in this comment). The first link in the answer is a legacy repo, links to this: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need a socket.io server without node.js, right? If to use socket.io just as cross-browser WebSockets would be sufficient, and what i mean by that is nicely illustrated in the following example from socket.io web site:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.send('hi');

  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    // my msg
  });
});
```

It would make your server code very simple. Surely, you can find some WebSockets library for your language or even write your own. Look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-sharp-web-socket-server) question for examples.

Or if you want to use socket.io [protocol](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) there is [list of socket.io libraries](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki/) for different languages, like python and java.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of noise in the answers to the original question. Let me try to answer the question as clear as I can.

> Is it possible to use socket.io without any node.js dependencies?

The short answer is yes. You will however have Flash dependency. You can read about how to do this in [socket.io's faq.](http://socket.io/docs/faq/)