# Socket.io client without node.js

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I would like to have a web page that connects (is a client) to socket.io/node.js backend,
but the web page should not be provided through/started using node.js,
but instead it should be a separate project without any node.js usage.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8182631/1482644

Comment: Different domain (or ip address) or same?

Answer (score 3):

[Socket.io](https://socket.io/) comes with two separate libraries, one for client usage and one for creating a server.
[The client library](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) can be used both in a web browser and also in a Node.js app.
[The server library](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) needs Node.js.

So it's important to implement your Socket.IO server with Node.js and then connect to it with the client library.

In order to use Socket.IO client library in a web page you should simply include it in the page using a `script` tag and then connect to your sever:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Your HTML page can be provided using any technology you want; For example you can produce the HTML page using Django framework and Python as its backend. Or simply run a web server (e.g Nginx) or even open the HTML page as a file in your browser of choice.

Answer (score 1):

It is not expressly required to use node on the server side. As an example, Flask has as server-side library using python:
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

socket.io also has a C server library, and I am sure there are a number of other languages that can use it. The issue here is that all the node documentation uses the "/socket.io/socket.io.js"script URL which implies that node.js is supplying the file *somehow* but we would like to get that file to serve without using Node.

In the flask example, it looks like they serve it using this script tag:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Depending on what your Server-side is using, they may have their own client-side implementation as well. I personally recommend reading the documentation for your socket.io implementation to see if they specify a client library.