# WebSockets Tutorial on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, websocket

Is there a simple, down to earth, sample/example/tutorial for WebSockets Server and Client implementation in ASP.NET 4.0 to get me started? I know this question has been asked, but it hasn't been answered properly. There is a lot of stuff about client side, but cannot find a simple explanation about server-side in ASP.NET

Thanks!

**~Update:**
I Found this tutorial, but cannot make it work, the connection closes right after attempting to connect. any one can make it work?
http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/06/html-5-c-web-sockets-server-and-asp-net-client-implementation/

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# web socket server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-sharp-web-socket-server)

Comment: have you looked at SignalR? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: Why has this been closed? 7 people have found it useful and 5 accepted the answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ASP.NET won't support WebSockets until Windows Server 8/IIS 8. See [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc303354469).

There's this tutorial, [Getting started with WebSockets in the Windows 8 developer preview](http://www.paulbatum.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-websockets-in.html), from September 2011.

If you want to see a working WebSocket server in .NET I'd recommend taking a look at [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) which is open source. If you just want to use a .NET WebSocket server then SuperWebSocket (again), [XSockets](http://xsockets.net) and [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) are worth a look.

SignalR also relies on Windows 8. See the [SignalR WebSockets docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Comment: I was looking for tutorial not the implementations. but will choose this as answer since you pointed me to Fleck which so far seems the simplest. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a tutorial using pure .NET WebSockets - no frameworks: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-2