# How to update value in textBox in ASP.NET in different thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I am working with a serial port device in asp.net.It works in different thread than UI thread.In its event I want to get access to my textbox and change its value.

```
void posInfo(string smth)
{
txtUI.text = smth;
}
```

this is giving me exception. how can i achieve this?

Comment: need to send the `txtUI` to your thread.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is disconnected protocol and the time your thread would send data you will not have connections to clients You will have to use some pooling solution  using javascript **[timer with Ajax](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/)** for updating the textbox asp.net. or you can use **[Web scoket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119900/websockets-tutorial-on-asp-net)** to update the GUI

Comment: we dont have InvokeRequire in asp.net. and also this.Invoke is not available in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

After the page is already rendered, you won't be able to change the textbox value. You'll have to do it with ajax or maybe something like signalr.