# SignalR always using longpolling

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, long-polling

I am using SignalR 2.0 beta.  From Chrome, Firefox, and IE10 I see the transport being used is always longPolling.

```
http://localhost:8080/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=123456
```

I am running a hub from a Windows Service, and have javascript hub proxies making connections as a client.

**Server-side code:**

```
WebApp.Start<StartUp>("http://*:8080");

public class StartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true };
        app.MapHubs(config);
    }
}
```

**Client-side code:**

```
function configureMessaging() {

var connectionMain = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:8080');
connectionMain.stateChanged(connectionStateChanged);
connectionMain.start({ waitForPageLoad: false, xdomain: false, jsonp: false });

var vmgrHub = connectionMain.createHubProxy("vmgrHub");

$("#broadcast").click(function () {
    vmgrHub.invoke('globalMessage', $("#msg").val());
});

vmgrHub.on('addGlobalMessage', function (message) {
    $("#message").text(message);
}); }
```

In production, the application will require cross-domain support, but in the example provided, the Windows Service and the javascript client are on localhost.

How can I get WebSockets to work in the browsers that support it?

Thanks!

Comment: is your application hosted on windows server 2012 or windows 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR w/ Web Sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601561/signalr-w-web-sockets)

Comment: The windows Service runs in Windows 2008 R2.  This is also my development environment.

Answer (score 2):

From [SignalR Supported Platforms](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms)

> Also note that for SignalR to use WebSockets, IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express
>   must be used, and the server must be using Windows 8, Windows Server
>   2012, or later.

Comment: OK, I think that is it.  I am going to setup a 2012 VM to prove this out... BUT, I am not sure why there is a requirement for WebSockets at the OS level.  IIS8 makes sense, but I am not using IIS.

Comment: Self-hosting using the Owin/Katana pieces still requires Windows Server 2012 for WebSockets as the dependency is on the version of HTTP.SYS in the OS. IIS and self-host both use HTTP.SYS and it didn't support WebSockets until Windows Server 2012.

Comment: That makes sense... I just setup a 2012 instance, and found the feature that installs Websockets... Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Application Development > Web Socket Protocol.