# does self hosted signalr require windows server 2012 in order to use websockets?

Tags: signalr

A self hosted application doesn't seem to run off of IIS, so does it require a specific operating system in order to enable web sockets on the server side?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Browsers will support it because they have implemented the protocol internally, most browsers won't use the operating system transport libraries so they will be able to make use of WebSockets even if the OS does not directly support it.

HTTP.SYS prior to Windows 8/2012 [has no built in support for WebSockets](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672604/websocket-support-missing-from-http-sys), so although .NET 4.5 contains WebSocket classes, they won't work unless you are running .NET 4.5+ on Windows 8/2012 and that will affect self-hosting solutions running in Windows < 8.

The implementation resides in the operating system code that .NET and IIS8 just leverages. The .NET classes simply wrap calls through to HTTP.SYS so it will throw an exception on an operating system that does not have underlying support for it.

When self-hosting you can however use your own internal Web Socket server such as [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) and tell SignalR that you in fact do support Web Sockets regardless of your OS.

Start a [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) server in your self-hosted application (examples on [their site](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)) and as an example you can do this for a *PersistentConnection* self-host:

```
public override Task ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
{
  // Override what SignalR will be telling you internally and point to your own Web Socket Server.
  context.Items[HostConstants.SupportsWebSockets] = true;
  context.Items[HostConstants.WebSocketServerUrl] = "ws://localhost:3000";
  return base.ProcessRequest(context);
}
```

Disclaimer: This is an undocumented feature, the developers of SignalR have told me that this may not be possible in future versions of the library. Keep in mind that you will also need to cater for keep-alives and serializing your data to JSON so it plays nice with the SignalR clients. It still works in version 1.1.3.

Comment: Well then the solution is simple. Just back-port HTTP.sys to earlier version! How #$%@%#@$ hard can the be? We have development hardware that we would love to move to Win8 but can't due to no win8 driver support, so we are stuck with win7.

Comment: I would like some more information on this.  I've been attempting to do something similar for a while and until now didn't know this was an option.  I have a custom websocket server listening on a port and I added the code you have above, referencing the port, but how do I go about getting the owin part to work with this?  For example, WebApp.Start< >('localhost:12345') starts an http listener for signal r.

Comment: @sqenixs You don't do anything differently when setting up SignalR, you just need to override `ProcessRequest` in classes that inherit from PersistentConnection or HubConnection. Owin has nothing to do with this question or the answer and completely off topic.

Comment: @BrutalDev I wouldn't say it is off-topic, as Signal R is built on OWIN according to Microsoft documentation.  When you start a self-hosted Signal R web app (which is via OWIN), how do you go about starting a websocket listener instead of http listener?  In my testing with your answer, websockets are not enabled/used in Signal R on the server side.

Comment: @sqenixs It's off topic, this is about enabling WebSockets when running on an operating system that would otherwise disable it, OWIN doesn't feature as it's just a decoupling interfacing standard... You still need an HTTP listener just like normal to negotiate the transport, nothing changes in that respect, when your server reports that it supports WebSockets (thanks to the override) then it will try to connect to the end-point you defined. This only works in SignalR 1, if you are using SignalR 2, MS have disabled the solution above on purpose and the above code is completely ignored.

Comment: @BrutalDev My mistake, I meant Katana when I said OWIN.  But the HTTP listener for the negotiate request is good information.  I didn't know that Signal R requires an HTTP connection for the negotiate request.  With this bit of information, I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I've know for sure that websockets are not supported now by doing a quick test. I created a self hosted hub and then a quick jquery client. On my windows 8 machine the querystring showed websockets, on the server 2008 r2 it showed long polling...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it requires windows server 2012 check the quote below from [SignalR Supported Platforms](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms)

> The SignalR server component can be hosted in the following server or
>   client operating systems. Note that for SignalR to use WebSockets,
>   Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 is required (WebSocket can be used on Windows Azure Web Sites, as long as the site's .NET framework version is set to 4.5, and Web Sockets is enabled in the site's Configuration page).

Also a good read on why can be found [here](http://deploytonenyures.blogspot.com/2013/04/self-hosting-and-httpsys.html)

Comment: Right, but that's only because it's using IIS through asp.net. A self hosted signalr woulnd't necessarily need IIS 8. Also, if you look at the source, it looks like WebSockets is baked into OWIN, as long as .net 4.5 is installed. I don't have the uber skills to read and know for sure, though, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @ton.yeung Actually no, it's an OS level feature, because even the client apps will need windows 8 to run, unless you are using a browser as the client then you will need a browser with HTML 5 support

Comment: how can it be an OS level feature if a browser that supports HTML5 will allow websockets?

Comment: @ton.yeung i can't say that i am 100% sure, but i think its because HTML 5 support it, and any browser that support HTML 5 need to include it disregarding the OS, so the browser will not depend on the OS while the .NET framework does

Comment: @ton.yeung: Browsers will support it if they have implemented the protocol internally, most browsers won't use the operating system transport libraries so they will be able to make use of WebSockets even if the OS does not directly support it. HTTP.SYS prior to Windows 8/2012 has no built in support for WebSockets, so although .NET 4.5 contains WebSocket classes, they won't work unless you are running on Windows 8/2012 and that will affect self-hosting. The implementation resides in the operating system code that .NET and IIS8 just leverages.

Comment: @BrutalDev would you mind posting this as an answer? This is by far the most complete answer and I'd like to give you credit for it.

Comment: @ton.yeung: Posted an answer as requested with a bit more info since I didn't have a character limit :)