# asp.net 5 web application with websockets on Windows 7

Tags: websocket, signalr, asp.net-core

I have a relatively simple web application that I am currently porting to asp.net 5. The current version runs under IIS on some Windows 7 and Server 2008 machines.
With the next version of my software I would like to connect a C++ client via SignalR to the web application. The problem is that the current version of the new Signalr-Cpp client only supports SignalR via websockets.
IIS on Windows 7 and Server 2008 does not support websockets, though.
Since a self-hosting solution would be fine for me, my question is:

Is it possible to support Signalr via websockets on Windows 7 / Server 2008 when the web app is self-hosted?

**Update:**

I would accept 
[does self hosted signalr require windows server 2012 in order to use websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957949/does-self-hosted-signalr-require-windows-server-2012-in-order-to-use-websockets) as an answer if there wasn't this small comment by Damian Edwards in the following [Tweet by David Fowler](https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/556007314692784129) which says

> although, with v3, websockets in a self-hosted server (like Katana) is possible

Does this change the situation?

**Final update**

At least with beta 6 it works on Windows 7 when hosting the app with Kestrel and including the middleware Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [does self hosted signalr require windows server 2012 in order to use websockets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957949/does-self-hosted-signalr-require-windows-server-2012-in-order-to-use-websockets)

Comment: You can use another framework for WebSockets. There is many, I created and maintain this one: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible...

[SignalR Supported Platforms](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms)

> for SignalR to use WebSockets, Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 is
>   required

[Does self hosted signalr require windows server 2012 in order to use websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957949/does-self-hosted-signalr-require-windows-server-2012-in-order-to-use-websockets)

> HTTP.SYS prior to Windows 8/2012 [has no built in support](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672604/websocket-support-missing-from-http-sys) for
>   WebSockets, so although .NET 4.5 contains WebSocket classes, they
>   won't work unless you are running .NET 4.5+ on Windows 8/2012 and that
>   will affect self-hosting solutions running in Windows < 8.

**UPDATE:**
My answer is valid for current release version of SignalR (2.2). Tweets you included (quite old btw) suggest this will be possible in v3 but its not released yet, there is not much info on Internet about changes\features of this release and I even can't find anything about WebSocket support in Katana on Win < 8 in [list of Github issues for v3](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3Av3%20websocket%20)

Comment: OK, I accept this as the answer since it is valid for the current release. I will try to make test applications with asp.net 5 and signalr 3 to see if this is still valid with the new versions.

Comment: I'm interested in what you find ... :)

Comment: Found this: host the app with Kestrel, include Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server and call app.UseWebSockets() in Configure(). This worked with ASP.NET5 beta 6 on Windows 7 :-)