# .NET MVC Long polling

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, long-polling

I want create method that will do some action when something added to the queue using `AsyncController`, here is my start:

```
public class AsyncTest : AsyncController
{
    public void LongPollAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        // search for messages and send them out...
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    }

    public ActionResult LongPollCompleted()
        {
        return Json();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Websockets, as this is what they are made for, AJAX has way too much overhead.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Can you please post an answer with examples how exactly to do this?

Comment: Where did you dug out `SocketController`? If you want comprehensible WebSocket tutorials follow this http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20
SignalR are able to use WebSocket transport

Comment: @testCoder `SocketController` is not real, it's just for example. Is teher any way to do this without using SignalR?

Comment: I only can give you links found by google, like this one: http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/ or this one http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: @DanFromGermany I don't want to use any external library, only `Microsoft` libraries.

Comment: Im not sure wether there are any WebSockets classes by Microsoft because basically websockets is a really simple protocol you would just open a TCP port and handle the data. Look at other related answers and google arround, you will find out how it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119900/websockets-tutorial-on-asp-net