# How to communicate between JS and WPF through WebView2

Tags: c#, reactjs, wpf, signalr, webview2

Recently we've been informed that we would be implementing new components for our product using `ReactJs` for future plans related reasons. However, we would depend on [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) in order to render these components within the current `WPF` App.

One of the challenges that we've faced is how to achieve `two-way communication` between the react component and the WPF App.

My team thought about using `SignalR` as a Mediator between the host and the component to achieve the communication, but not sure if this is the best solution in this case.

Yes, there is a facility provided by the `WebView2` to `invoke` scripts against the component but this would achieve a one-way communication from the `WPF` App to the `react` component.

So what is needed now is how to achieve the vice-versa, Invoking something from the react component against the WPF App. Is there are any better solutions for this case?

Comment: may be something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537641/node-js-socket-io-vs-signalr-vs-c-sharp-websocket-server

Comment: CoreWebView2 can communicate with the Document using [PostWebMessageAsJson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.postwebmessageasjson) (the Document adds an EventListener for `message`) and the Document with the application using `window.chrome.webview.postMessage(json)` -- The EventListener can be part of the Document or added later calling `ExecuteScriptAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I've just released [WebView2.DevTools.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/) to [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/amaitland). It's free for anyone to use.

More details and examples in the [Readme](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#webview2-devtools-dom).

You can expose a function to your JavaScript application to call.

```cs
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += async (s, e) =>
{
                var devToolsContext = await webView.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

                await devToolsContext.ExposeFunctionAsync("jsAlertButtonClick", () =>
                {
                    _ = devToolsContext.EvaluateExpressionAsync("window.alert('Hello! You invoked window.alert()');");
                });

                await devToolsContext.ExposeFunctionAsync("csAlertButtonClick", () =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        WindowState = WindowState switch
                        {
                            WindowState.Maximized => WindowState.Normal,
                            WindowState.Normal => WindowState.Maximized,
                            _ => WindowState.Minimized,
                        };
                    });
                });

                var meaningOfLifeAsInt = await devToolsContext.EvaluateFunctionAsync<int>("() => Promise.resolve(42)");

                var jsAlertButton = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#jsAlertButton");
                var csAlertButton = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#csAlertButton");

                _ = jsAlertButton.AddEventListenerAsync("click", "jsAlertButtonClick");
                _ = csAlertButton.AddEventListenerAsync("click", "csAlertButtonClick");

                var innerText = await jsAlertButton.GetPropertyValueAsync<string>("innerText");

                var currentTimeSpan = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#current-time");
                var fpsSpan = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#fps");

                await devToolsContext.ExposeFunctionAsync<double, bool>("requestAnimationFrameCallback", (highResTime) =>
                {
                    var duration = NodaTime.Duration.FromNanoseconds(Math.Round(highResTime * 1000) * 1000);

                    callback(duration);

                    return false;
                });

                callback(NodaTime.Duration.Zero);

                void callback(NodaTime.Duration timestamp)
                {
                    _ = currentTimeSpan.SetInnerText(GetCurrentDateTime());
                    _ = fpsSpan.SetInnerText(CalculateFps(timestamp).ToString());

                    _ = devToolsContext.EvaluateExpressionAsync(@"window.requestAnimationFrame((x) => { window.requestAnimationFrameCallback(x)});");
                }
};
```

Functions persist across navigations so you only need to register a function once.

There's a working example available at https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/blob/main/WebView2.DevTools.Dom.Wpf.Example/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L22