# WebSockets: IIS: TcpServerSocket

Tags: websocket

I might be posting in the wrong place, but, I have a question. I have a web application that is hosted on IIS. And I have TCpSocketServers running on several separate machines listening on separate ports. My requirement is for the web application to connect to the tcpserver and get realtime data. My thought originally was to write an ASP.NET Core SignalR Hub hosted on my IIS(ssl enabled) which in turn acts as a tcp client to the servers. Is this possible? If not, what are my options? I'm not clear as to how the Asp.net core signalr app can be made a tcp client.

[Node.Js + Socket.IO vs SignalR vs C# WebSocket Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537641/node-js-socket-io-vs-signalr-vs-c-sharp-websocket-server)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a SignalR Server in ASP.NET Core(that would connect to a TcpServer) and a javascript client.