# Refresh client browser when adding new line in a specific table

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

My scenario:

After client login, my user will be redirected to the index.aspx page.
Inside this page I will put one div with a gridview inside.
This gridview will be showing data from one table.

> My question is: How to refresh this gridview always that one record is
>   saved on this table?

Ps.: I´ve seen a lot of examples using "server push" tecnology, comet, ajax, etc.
Don´t know the best way to do that and can´t find a really simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new record is added to the table, the real challenge is communicating those changes to the client in real-time without polling in intervals or requiring some sort of user interaction.

You have a couple of options:

1. Your best bet is to use a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which enables bidirectional communication between the client and server. This is the solution I would pick.

   Here are some examples using `WebSockets`:

   - [Building real-time web apps with WebSockets using IIS, ASP.NET and WCF](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-807T)
   - [HTML5 C# WebSockets Server and ASP.NET Client Implementation](http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/06/html-5-c-web-sockets-server-and-asp-net-client-implementation/)
   - [C# WebSocket Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-sharp-web-socket-server)
   - [WebSockets in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/websockets-in-asp-net-4-5/)
   - [WebHooks and WebSockets in ASP.NET](http://www.entechsolutions.com/hooks-and-sockets-for-web-apps)

   There are a few good libraries around too that will take care of most of the leg work. A couple to check out are [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/downloads#server) and [PokeIn](http://www.pokein.com/Products/Downloads.aspx). Both products offer decent documentation and community editions that you can download for free.

   Here are some tutorials to check out:

   - [WebSync Tutorials](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/tutorials/v3)
   - [PokeIn Basic Tutorial](http://www.pokein.com/Help/BasicTutorial.aspx) / [PokeIn Advanced Tutorial](http://www.pokein.com/Help/AdvancedTutorial.aspx)
2. Use AJAX to poll for changes every `X` number of seconds. If changes are detected reload the page, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: **Use AJAX to poll for changes every X number of seconds. If changes are detected reload the page, otherwise do nothing.** Can you tell please how should I calculate the changes made ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: What do you mean calculate the changes made? Make an AJAX call to a function that passes in the number of records displayed and returns a boolean. The method will return a row count, and if `recordsDisplayed != existingRecords`, rebind the grid with an asynchronous callback.

Comment: @abcdefghi: The question asks **when add new line in a specific table** and does not mention updates. However, there are a number of ways to handle updates with the given approach too.

Comment: It's important to note however that I'm advocating the use of `WebSockets` for this, not AJAX polling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setinterval  javascript method. I act as a timer and use submit form to refresh the page. other method could be asp.net ajax toolkit timer control [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

put your grid inside an update panel and set "Update Mode" to always

Comment: Can you please tell, How should I refresh this gridview ?

Comment: When it is inside an update panel and update mode is always, every change to the grid will be capture and refresh. You don't need to do anything else I think.

Comment: So, Can i do it without Update Panel?

Comment: You can refresh the page can load your grid at pageload. UpdatePanel is better since it looks smooth and easy to implement. Try it u'll like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update Panel which uses AJAX under the hood. Refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) for a short and simple demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain old html

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"
CONTENT="15;URL=http://www.I18nGuy.com/index.html">
```