# What are the different between Super Web Socket and Nugget?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

I have implemented my application in C# with use of Supper Web Socket the.NET implementation of WebSocket server.  I have heard about the Nugget which is another .NET Web Socket server.  What are the key differences?   I have been to the website 'nugget.codeplex.com' but could not find useful info. I would like to know from someone who had experience with Nugget.

Comment: Firstly, forcing people to answer your questions won't get you anywhere.. Secondly, why not try and see for yourself? I don't use any of these, but my approach would be to get both, study the documentation and try to perform some tasks. Then I'd just pick the one I feel more comfortable with.

Comment: As I said above I have already created my application on SuperWebSocket.  I have been to the website http://nugget.codeplex.com/ but could not find useful info.  I would like to know from someone who had experience with Nugget.  If you do not like the question, downgrade it.  why wrote irrelevance or advisable sentences?

Comment: I was hoping to give you some directions, that helped me in the past when no one wanted/could answer my questions, but it seems my experiences are irrelevant for you. No problem. Just one note - look at the last update date on Nugget site. Released 13.9.2010 and it's still in phase Alpha, while last update is from 29.9.2010. If you really think someone here has some serious experiences with Nugget, then good luck. All indices show the project is dead for 2 years. Anyway, I won't plague your question by useless comments anymore.

Comment: The last update date on Nugget site, helped me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://nugget.codeplex.com/documentation

[Websocket server: onopen function on the web socket is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-sharp-websocket-server)

http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/06/html-5-c-web-sockets-server-and-asp-net-client-implementation/

http://jxs.me/2011/05/28/csharp-websockets-with-fleck/

A simple Google search came up with this. Please understand that there is a vast multitude of services and libraries in existence and the best way is not to demand expertise but to call on someone who might have some, if any knowledge. Try to implement both along side each other yourself and see the differences based on the documentation. My guess will be that there is very little difference except for how the code is wrapped or the algorithmic approached. Both, if they do the same thing, should do what you want them to fairly well. Its Apples and Oranges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not apples and oranges! I have found some advantages yesterday.  One of the advantages is : the SuperWebSocket support Mono