# C# WebSocket Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mono, websocket, mamp

I am using the momo mac project, to develop and compile a C# websocket on OS X Mountain Lion.
 I've used the example websocket from [Websocket server: onopen function on the web socket is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-sharp-websocket-server) to just get an idea of how it's working. My problem is, I don't know how to host the websocket.

I've put it in the root directory of my MAMP localhost folder, and linked to it, like in the example code, at this path **localhost:8181/websession**.

Problem is the socket just fires the onclose event immediately. There's no call to the onerror function, so no error data.

1. How do I run the C# Program on OS X?
2. Where do I put the WebSocket?

Comment: are you using [**SuperSocket**](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/)? If yes, they do nice [tutorials](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/documentation) and one of them is how to [host on OSX](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Run%20SuperSocket%20in%20Unix%2fLinux%20by%20Mono).

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm trying to connect to my socket using html5 socket, but I don't have any programs helping me run it. I'll check it out though. Thanks.

Comment: But when you **`Run`** your website from Mono (the server) it does open a page right? your HTML5 client page just need to connect to that URL.

Comment: The example websocket server you linked to is pretty old.  It implements an obsolete draft of the protocol which no up-to-date browser will understand.  I'd suggest you start by reading the [latest spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) then update your handshake code.  That should stop onclose running immediately on the client.

Comment: It runs, and alerts connection closed.

Comment: @simonc The link you posted, contains quite alot of text. Maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Start with the [handshaking section](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-4.2).  You could also take inspiration from [previous SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-wold-websocket-example)

Comment: Thanks. Lots of reading to do I guess. :)