# How can I connect to a websocket in C# with Windows 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, websocket

I just started looking at examples for connecting to a websocket in C# and realised they all use .NET 4.5. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 - are there any examples or libraries available for this?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898

Comment: No, I'm looking to connect to a websocket not setup a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) - very easy to build and use.

Comment: The problem is that they don't have any releases.  You're stuck with using master branch and recompiling it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) as
  websocket server and
  [Websocket4net](http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/) as websocket
  client.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot host web sockets on IIS 7.5 but you can host your own web server using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)

You can download it from github or type fleck in nuget.

Create your webserver socket

```
// Create Websocket server
websocketServer = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:82");
websocketServer.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.OnOpen = () => Console.WriteLine("Open!");
    socket.OnClose = () => Console.WriteLine("Close!");
    socket.OnMessage = message => socket.Send(message);
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to host a websocket server - read the question.